Replacing loops with apply/mapply/etc. to speed things up
I have the following code that uses a nested loop. This uses sample random data and sample (smallish, relative to the actual application) numbers N, Taumax, and Tmax.
N <- 10000
Taumax <- 50
Tmax <- 100

set.seed(42)

X1 <- matrix(rnorm(N * (Tmax+1)), N)
X2 <- matrix(rnorm(N * (Tmax+1)), N)
X3 <- matrix(rnorm(N * (Tmax+1)), N)
Phi <- matrix(rnorm(Taumax * (Tmax+1)), Taumax)
Psi <- matrix(rnorm(Taumax * 3), Taumax)

y <- array(0.0, dim = c(N, Taumax, (Tmax + 1)))
for (t in 1:(Tmax + 1)) {
  for (tau in 1:Taumax) {
    y[, tau, t] <-
      exp(-(
        Phi[tau, t] + Psi[tau, 1] * X1[, t] +
          Psi[tau, 2] * X2[, t] +
          Psi[tau, 3] * X3[, t]
      ) / tau) - 1
  }
}

I'm curious whether it is possible to significantly speed up the loop bit (ie, the last bit) of the code by using, eg, apply, mapply or some other sort of vectorization (or matrix algebra, for that matter). I have used apply before, but I'm far from using it proficiently.
One thing that could spell trouble is that one of the loop indexes (tau) features as a factor in the ultimate calculation.
(There's also this thing with X1, X2, X3, which together can also be an array X. But is there a way that that would also speed up things?)

You could try replacing the inner loop with the outer() function and this could provide a speed up.
Today, the "for" loops are not significantly slower than the apply functions, so there may not be a benefit.
N <- 10000
Taumax <- 50
Tmax <- 100

set.seed(42)

X1 <- matrix(rnorm(N * (Tmax+1)), N)
X2 <- matrix(rnorm(N * (Tmax+1)), N)
X3 <- matrix(rnorm(N * (Tmax+1)), N)
Phi <- matrix(rnorm(Taumax * (Tmax+1)), Taumax)
Psi <- matrix(rnorm(Taumax * 3), Taumax)

y <- array(0.0, dim = c(N, Taumax, (Tmax + 1)))
for (t in 1:(Tmax + 1)) {
   for (tau in 1:Taumax) {
      y[, tau, t] <-
         exp(-(
            Phi[tau, t] + Psi[tau, 1] * X1[, t] +
               Psi[tau, 2] * X2[, t] +
               Psi[tau, 3] * X3[, t]
         ) / tau) - 1
   }
}

#Replace the inner loop with the outer function: %o%
z <- array(0.0, dim = c(N, Taumax, (Tmax + 1)))
for (t in 1:(Tmax + 1)) {
   z[,,t] <- t(exp(-(Phi[,t] + Psi[, 1] %o% X1[,t] + Psi[,2] %o% X2[,t] + Psi[,3] %o% X3[,t]) /c(1:Taumax)) -1)
}

#compare results
identical(y, z)

Update
Using the microbenchmark package, there doesn't seem to be much of an improvement:
Unit: seconds
  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 Org() 2.349934 2.416134 2.462019 2.437054 2.515235 2.641641   100
 new() 1.988689 2.053746 2.093798 2.094842 2.127008 2.250958   100

Maybe try rewriting the function using Rcpp.

We can rewrite the function so that it can be translated to C/C++ and then complied via the nimble package.  I tried this with the reduced sizes shown in the Note at the end since I am on a slow laptop but you can try repeating this with the desired sizes.  With the the benchmark shown it ran in less than half the time of the loop code in the question even though the code is nearly identical.
library(microbenchmark)
library(nimble)

calc <- nimbleFunction(
  run = function(Phi = double(2), Psi = double(2),
      X1 = double(2), X2 = double(2), X3 = double(2)) {
    N <- dim(X1)[1]
    Taumax <- dim(Psi)[1]
    Tmax1 <- dim(X1)[2]
    y <- array(dim = c(N, Taumax, Tmax1), init = FALSE)
    for (t in 1:Tmax1) {
      for (tau in 1:Taumax) {
        y[, tau, t] <-
           exp(-(
              Phi[tau, t] + Psi[tau, 1] * X1[, t] +
                 Psi[tau, 2] * X2[, t] +
                 Psi[tau, 3] * X3[, t]
           ) / tau) - 1
       }
    }
    return(y)
    returnType(double(3))
})
Ccalc <- compileNimble(calc)
y.nimble <- Ccalc(Phi, Psi, X1, X2, X3)

Now benchmark it against the code in the question
microbenchmark(
  nimble = { 
    y.nimble <- Ccalc(Phi, Psi, X1, X2, X3)
  },
  loop = {
    y <- array(0.0, dim = c(N, Taumax, (Tmax + 1)))
    for (t in 1:(Tmax + 1)) {
      for (tau in 1:Taumax) {
        y[, tau, t] <-
           exp(-(
              Phi[tau, t] + Psi[tau, 1] * X1[, t] +
                 Psi[tau, 2] * X2[, t] +
                 Psi[tau, 3] * X3[, t]
           ) / tau) - 1
     }
  }
})

## Unit: microseconds
##    expr    min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval
##  nimble  669.2  700.90  834.472  726.8  830.55  6467.0   100
##    loop 1914.8 1985.95 2291.083 2060.6 2234.90 18090.2   100

identical(y, y.nimble)
## [1] TRUE

Note
Inputs from question (reduced)
N <- 10000/100
Taumax <- 50/10
Tmax <- 100/10

set.seed(42)

X1 <- matrix(rnorm(N * (Tmax+1)), N) # N by Tmax+1
X2 <- matrix(rnorm(N * (Tmax+1)), N)
X3 <- matrix(rnorm(N * (Tmax+1)), N)
Phi <- matrix(rnorm(Taumax * (Tmax+1)), Taumax) # Taumax by Tmax+1
Psi <- matrix(rnorm(Taumax * 3), Taumax) # Taumax by 3


That's quick. I have multiple loopy segments elsewhere in my extended R code that together run for half an hour or so. It looks like I might give them all the same treatment. Thanks!
